# Copy text output to clipboard

Tags: r, latex, clipboard, stargazer

I am using the package `stargazer` to generate LaTeX tables. The output of `stargazer()` is the code for the table, in plain text. Is there a way to automatically copy this text output to the clipboard, so it can be pasted into a separate file?

As a simple example:

```
> library(stargazer)
> stargazer(attitude)

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
rating & 30 & 64.633 & 12.173 & 40 & 85 \\ 
complaints & 30 & 66.600 & 13.315 & 37 & 90 \\ 
privileges & 30 & 53.133 & 12.235 & 30 & 83 \\ 
learning & 30 & 56.367 & 11.737 & 34 & 75 \\ 
raises & 30 & 64.633 & 10.397 & 43 & 88 \\ 
critical & 30 & 74.767 & 9.895 & 49 & 92 \\ 
advance & 30 & 42.933 & 10.289 & 25 & 72 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I'm using RStudio on a mac.

Comment: Maybe the following is useful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clipr/index.html

Comment: Ah! That was easy!